# Show alert message box from the Global.asax (on Application_Error event)

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, error-handling, global-asax

Normally I just redirect to a custom error page in on the Application_Error event, but I have a specific error for which I'd like to display an alert message while the user is still on the page which triggers the error.  How can I make this happen?

I'm open to a modalpopup or any other type of error message, I just want to ensure the user stays on the page where they encounter the error.

Thank for any ideas.

This is in reference to this thread: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected: Dealing with these errors proactively, or after the fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464341/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-dealing-with-these-error)

Here is the code I'm currently using:

> ```
> Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
>     'Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
>     Try
>         Dim err As Exception = Server.GetLastError
>         If err.Message IsNot Nothing Then
>             If err.Message = "The client disconnected." Then
>                 Dim LogError As New LogError(Server.GetLastError, Session, Request)
>                 LogError.LogError()
>                 Response.Redirect("~/TimeoutPage.aspx?id=2")
>             ElseIf err.Message.Contains("dangerous Request.Form value") Then
>                 'Response.Redirect("~/MyInputErrorPage.aspx")
>             'Instead the above redirect, I'd like to show the user an alertbox or something similar to explain the error to them
>             Else
>                 Dim LogError As New LogError(Server.GetLastError, Session, Request)
>                 LogError.LogError()
>                 Response.Redirect("~/MyErrorPage.aspx")
>             End If
>         End If
>     Catch ex As Exception
>     End Try
> ```

Comment: Can you define a specific situation you need this functionality for? Once the user clicks something and triggers a request, they aren't really "on the page" anymore.

Why don't you just add error handling to the page itself?

Comment: There are a large number of pages which could trigger this error and I don't want to have to update all of them..that's why I'm trying to handle this in the Global.asax

Please see the revised question...this is about catching errors when the user inputs potentially dangerous characters like the < and > characters...and I don't want to have to do validation for those characters on every page/input control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out an easy way to do this, so I just made new error page for these types of errors, and Redirect to that page when that specific error is caught in the Application_Error event (as my code in the first post indicates).

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the error occurs, wrap it in a try-catch block and handle it in the code behind page load.

If you want a Javascript styled modal pop-up error, in the catch, write out a flag value / error message to a hidden variable on the page and handle it in the html document load.

Comment: Hmm, then here's another thought - in the Global.asax, in the "on request" handler capture the requested URL. When you trap the error redirect the request back to the page, but inject code to cause a pop-up.

Comment: Are you using a base page that your pages inherit from?  If so put the code to handle this in there

Comment: ^ Actually I do use a master page, I might try that later. Thanks